# My code-first approach for SOAP in spring is not generating the XSDs and WSDL correctly

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I've created a SOAP service by following this example pretty much to the letter:
https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot-start

But I want to follow a code-first (bottom up) approach so rather than write the xsd and generate the java from it, I write the java and generate the xsd from it like so:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schemagen</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schemagen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                            <sources>
                                <source>../soapservice-api/src/main/java/techbasics/soapservice/api/v1</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and then add the xsds to the classpath, which is then used to generate the wsdl. This works great except that the jaxb2-maven-plugin only picks up the objects annotated with `java.xml.bind` annotations like `@XmlElement` and so on, and so only generates "model" objects in the xsd files.

The problem is I don't know how to make it distinguish between model classes (which are generated fine) and the endpoint class containing the operations:

Model class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Builder @Data
@XmlType(namespace = SoapService.NAMESPACE_URI_V1)
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "qualifications", nillable = true)
    @XmlElement(name = "qualification")
    private List<String> qualifications;
}
```

Service class:

```
public class SoapService {
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://localhost:8000/soapService/v1", localPart = "processPerson")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ProcessedPerson processPerson(Person person) {
        //do stuff
        return return new ProcessedPerson();
    }
}
```

Generated XSDs:

schema1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/soapService/v1" version="1.0">

  <xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="qualifications" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="qualification" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="processedPerson">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="over18" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="numberOfQualifications" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

schema2.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

  <xs:complexType name="soapService">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Of course this generates a wsdl without any operations:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:sch="http://localhost:8000/soapService/v1"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8000/soapService/v1" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/soapService/v1">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/soapService/v1" version="1.0">
            <xs:complexType name="person">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="qualifications" nillable="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="qualification" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="processedPerson">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="over18" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="numberOfQualifications" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:portType name="SoapServiceV1Port"></wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SoapServiceV1PortSoap11" type="tns:SoapServiceV1Port">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SoapServiceV1PortService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:SoapServiceV1PortSoap11" name="SoapServiceV1PortSoap11">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/soapservice/v1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

How can I generate the XSDs (and therefore the wsdl) correctly?

Comment: There's a reason why most people use a design-first approach. What's your reason for the code-first approach?

Comment: I guess it's a personal preference. I'm quite adept at api design and prefer to maintain only one view of an api (the java view) rather than java and xsd/wsdl which has to be kept in sync. In my experience if your endpoints are properly versioned and you know who's consuming which version, the risk of accidentally breaking an endpoint for somebody becomes quite low.

Comment: Fair enough, and clearly explained. I think you're fighting the system, though. SOAP / Swagger / OpenAPI / RAML are all designed as a means to document the contract between client and server. All of the associated frameworks and technologies assume that you will be starting with a model. It's not surprising that doing it the other way around is difficult.